# Identifying the Number of Positions then Outputting the Positions and Number in another Column

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

Hi everyone, Im new to VBA and StackOverflow. Currently, I am trying to use VBA to create a process to summarise the data that I have collected.The above photo is a part of the long macro process that I am facing issues with. I need to find the number of unique positions in column "A" (new positions can be added in over time), then output the unique positions into the positions column in column "J". After that, in column "K", I would need to count the number of each unique rank.

As of now, I have the following code to find for a position.

```
Sub test ()
Dim Manager as Integer
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Manager = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"), "Manager")
'Output the Manager value anywhere as require
End Sub
```

However, I face challenges in identifying the unique positions, counting the unique positions and then outputting the number of unique positions beside the position. Is this even possible in VBA?

Thanks so much

Comment: What does "unique position" mean? Fill in the screenshot with the desired results and explain the logic that leads to the result. -- How about adding a column with a unique number and then creating a pivot table with "minimum" as the aggregate? Anyway, it's not clear what you want to achieve. Edit **your question** to provide these details. Do NOT post details in comments.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Would be nice if you could include a screenshot of the expected result. Of Course that is posible with VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you may be over-complicating things and asking for VBA because you may not know that things can be done without VBA. As I understand the question, you want a count of each position in column A. That can easily be done with a pivot table, without re-inventing the wheel with VBA. Pivot tables are much more powerful and much faster than conventional formulas and DEFINITELY faster than any VBA that you can come up with.

Consider this screenshot:

[image]

I've turned column A into an Excel Table object with Insert > Table (or Ctrl-T), so the data can grow easily, but that is optional.

Then I've inserted a pivot table and pulled the Position into the Rows area and pulled it again into the values area, where it is aggregated with a count.

No formulas, no VBA.

If that is not what you need, edit your question and clarify. Otherwise, feel free to mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create "Temp" sheet first then execute this VBA below:

```
    Sub ExtractUnique()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim shTemp As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Set sh = ActiveSheet 'or change to your sheet name Sheets("your sheet")
    LastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

   'temporary sheet
   Set shTemp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp") 'MAKE SURE YOU CREATE 'Temp' sheet first!!!

   'copy your positions to temporary sheet for manipulation
   sh.Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Copy
   shTemp.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlValues
   Application.CutCopyMode = False

   'remove duplicates
   shTemp.Range("A1:A" & LastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes

   'copy it back to J1 of your original sheet
   'first check the last row of unique position list
   LastRow = shTemp.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

   shTemp.Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Copy
   sh.Range("J1").PasteSpecial xlValues
   Application.CutCopyMode = False

   'set the formula to count the number of positions
   sh.Range("K2:K" & LastRow).Formula = "=COUNTIF(A:A,J2)"

   End Sub
```